# Is it possible to store document fields in a SearchKit index?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible in SearchKit (on OS X) to actually store document fields in the search index, as it is possible in some other search libraries? This would allow for quickly displaying certain fields (author, subject, date, etc) without having to read the files corresponding to the underlying documents as the result of a search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want to be able to read the attributes or do you want to be able to search against them? If you want to be able to read them, you can add them as attributes to your document via the `SKIndexSetDocumentProperties` call. You then retrieve them with the `SKIndexCopyDocumentProperties` call. In both cases, the properties are stored in a dictionary.

This assumes you know how to read the properties from the file and you're not just blindly relying on the Search Kit / Spotlight importers.

If you want to be able to search against the properties, you're probably going to have a search index for the properties you want to search.

Comment: Ah, sweet! Those were the methods I was looking for, but I did not expect them to begin with `SKIndex...`. Thanks!